Rust Return self if not changed or new Self if changed (Copy on Write)
I have a struct with function remove, and I want the remove function to return new instance if actually removed or the same reference
But I get Cannot move when trying to return *self
Is it possible?
From the errors I don't think so, but then how Cow is possible.
Code:
use std::collections::HashMap;

#[derive(Clone)]
struct Something {
    data: HashMap<char, u16>,
}

impl Something {
    fn new() -> Self {
        return Something {
            data: HashMap::new()
        }
    }

    fn get(&self, c: char) -> Option<&u16> {

        return self.data.get(&c);
    }

    fn add(&self, c: char, value: u16) -> Self {
        let mut n = self.clone();

        n.data.insert(c, value);

        return n;
    }

    fn remove(&self, c: char) -> Self {
        if !self.data.contains_key(&c) {
            return *self; // <-- error[E0507]: cannot move out of `*self` which is behind a shared reference
        }

        let mut n = self.clone();
        n.data.remove(&c);

        return n;
    }
}

fn main() {
    let s = Something::new();

    let s = s.add('a', 1);
    let s = s.add('b', 2);

    let s = s.remove('a');

    // Should return the same instance as c is missing
    let s = s.remove('c');
}

but If I change the remove function to return &Self then I can't return a reference to a variable declared in the function:
    fn remove(&self, c: char) -> &Self {
        if !self.data.contains_key(&c) {
            return self;
        }

        let mut n = self.clone();
        n.data.remove(&c);

        return &n;  // <--- error[E0515]: cannot return reference to local variable `n`
    }

I know I can avoid borrowing something but I don't want to move ownership:
    // <--- self and not &self
    fn remove(self, c: char) -> Self {
        if !self.data.contains_key(&c) {
            return self;  
        }

        let mut n = self.clone();
        n.data.remove(&c);

        return n;
    }

Because then the following will fail:
fn main() {
    let s = Something::new();

    let s = s.add('a', 1);
    let s = s.add('b', 2);

    let s1 = s.remove('a');
    let s2 = s.remove('a'); // <-- error[E0382]: use of moved value: `s`
}


There is a built-in Copy-on-write type (Cow) that should work for your case.

Can't I implement it myself?

A &self->Self method will always have to clone. That's a fundamental thing about ownership.
There are two possible solutions to this, besides the obvious one of "just clone":

Make it &self->&self. Of course, then you won't be able to modify it, but Cow can solve that:
use std::borrow::Cow;

fn remove(&self, c: char) -> Cow<'_, Self> {
    if !self.data.contains_key(&c) {
        return Cow::Borrowed(self);
    }

    let mut n = self.clone();
    n.data.remove(&c);

    Cow::Owned(n)
}


Use a cheaply cloneable data structure that also allows Copy-On-Write, such as Rc or Arc:
use std::rc::Rc;
use std::collections::HashMap;

#[derive(Clone)]
struct Something {
    data: Rc<HashMap<char, u16>>,
}

impl Something {
    fn new() -> Self {
        Something {
            data: Rc::new(HashMap::new()),
        }
    }

    fn get(&self, c: char) -> Option<&u16> {
        self.data.get(&c)
    }

    fn add(&self, c: char, value: u16) -> Self {
        let mut this = self.clone();
        let n = Rc::make_mut(&mut this.data);
        n.insert(c, value);
        this
    }

    fn remove(&self, c: char) -> Self {
        let mut this = self.clone();

        if !this.data.contains_key(&c) {
            return this;
        }

        let n = Rc::make_mut(&mut this.data);
        n.remove(&c);
        this
    }
}




Could also use the normal Cow, or instead of returning "self or new self" return a Some in case of new version and a None otherwise and let the caller deal with that.
